# Removing and re-adding elements to a vector

Tags: c++, vector, erase, openframeworks, particles

Hi i'm somewhat new with c++ and openframeworks and I'm trying to get my program running more smooth by erasing the element from the vector when it goes out of the screen. At the moment as the time goes on it still gets slower and slower. I'm breaking my head over this. If you have any idea how I could improve this.

```
bool isDead(Particle &p) {
    if (p.position.x > ofGetWindowWidth() || p.position.x == -1 || p.position.y > ofGetWindowHeight() || p.position.y == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::setup() {


    ofSetFrameRate(60);
    ofEnableAlphaBlending();
    ofBackground(ofColor::black);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        Particle p;
        p.setup(ofVec2f(ofRandom(ofGetWindowWidth() * 0.45, ofGetWindowWidth() * 0.55), ofRandom(ofGetWindowHeight() * 0.45, ofGetWindowHeight() * 0.55)));
        particles.push_back(p);
    }

    beat1.load("beat1.wav");
    beat2.load("beat2.wav");
    beat3.load("beat3.wav");

    fftSmooth = new float[8192];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8192; i++) {
        fftSmooth[i] = 0;
    }

    bands = 128;
    beat1.setVolume(0.2);
    beat2.setVolume(0.2);
    beat3.setVolume(0.2);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::update() {

    ofSoundUpdate();

    float * value = ofSoundGetSpectrum(bands);
    for (int i = 0; i < bands; i++) {
        fftSmooth[i] *= 0.2f;
        if (fftSmooth[i] < value[i]) {
            fftSmooth[i] = value[i];
        }
    }

    ofRemove(particles, isDead);

    for (Particle& p : particles) {
        if (!p.isActive) {
            p.position = ofVec2f(ofRandom(ofGetWindowWidth() * 0.45, ofGetWindowWidth() * 0.55), ofRandom(ofGetWindowHeight() * 0.45, ofGetWindowHeight() * 0.55));
            p.isActive = true;
            return;
        }
        p.update();
    }



    if (isDead) {
        Particle p;
        p.setup(ofVec2f(0, 0));
        particles.push_back(p);
    }

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::draw() {
    for (Particle& p1 : particles) {
        if (!p1.isActive) continue;


        bool foundConnection = false;
        //search for connections.
        for (Particle& p2 : particles) {
            if (!p2.isActive || p2.drawPosition == p1.drawPosition) continue;

            float distance = p1.drawPosition.distance(p2.drawPosition);

            for (int i = 0; i < bands; i++) {
                if (distance > 10 && distance < 50 * fftSmooth[i]) {
                    ofDrawLine(p1.drawPosition, p2.drawPosition);
                    foundConnection = true;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            p1.draw(-(fftSmooth[i] * 10));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ofRemove(particles, isDead);` what's this function's definition?

Comment: particles is the vector, isDead is the boolean function, it performs remove_if and erase

Comment: What is the body of that `ofRemove` function? Perhaps you're not removing? Also, removing from `std::vector` (unless from the back) takes `O(n)` time.

Comment: void ofRemove(vector<T>& values, BoolFunction shouldErase) {
 values.erase(remove_if(values.begin(), values.end(), shouldErase), values.end());
}

Comment: @Vik If you're going to use `std::vector` you should use it where it counts, such as `fftSmooth = new float[8192];`.  That could have been a `std::vector<float> fftSmooth;` then `fftSmooth.resize(8192);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie or just `std::vector<float> fftSmooth(8192);`...